# Singapore Tourist visa extension

Tags: tourist-visas, singapore, visa-extensions

My friend has a tourist visa to Singapore for 30 days. He already visited Singapore once. And for his next visit, the 30-day period expires. Can he get the visa period extended for another 15 days or so?

Comment: Hi, when you say visa, do you mean an entry stamp which allows entry for 30 days, or a visa applied and a sticker placed on it? It will be also great to know your friend's nationality.

Comment: And also the amount of time / number of visits your friend has made to Singapore in the recent past

Comment: One point is not clear: whether the visa expires before or after his intended entry into Singapore: extension of the visa can be done only if it has a remaining validity of not less than 2 days (excluding Sunday and public holidays).

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the visa after entering Singapore. You can extend the Visa upto 90 days.

Details: https://extend.ica.gov.sg/extend/index.xhtml

FAQ: https://extend.ica.gov.sg/extend/xhtml/StaticPages/Faq.xhtml

Comment: Although you have the right links, one detail appears not to be correct: e-XTEND is an online service and does not involve agents, residents/citizens, only the Immigration & Checkpoints Authority.